# How can a mock a http observable in Angular2 for when no api is written

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I'm new to both Angular2 and Rxjs and I am a little confused about a particular case.

I have a simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

export interface Article {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  author: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
  private _articles$: Subject<Article[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  private dataStore: {
    articles: Article[]
  };
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
    this.dataStore = { articles: [] };
    this._articles$ = <Subject<Article[]>>new Subject();
  }
  get articles$(){
    return this._articles$.asObservable();
  }

  loadAll(){
    //Observable.from(this.dummyData)
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/articles`)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      //debugger;
      this.dataStore.articles = data;
       // Push a new copy of our article list to all Subscribers.
      this._articles$.next(this.dataStore.articles)
    }, error => console.log('Could not load Articles'));
  }
}
```

And this works as expected , but what I would like to do is to be able to develope my service without a api endpoint and using an Observable that I can later swap out for the `http.request` . I tried to do this using Observable.from to convert a dummy data array to an observable but I get the errors

> `Type '{ id: number; title: string; content: string; author: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Article[]'`

I believe this is because it is returning each item separately instead of the array , can someone point me in the correct direction of how this should work

**Update**:
for clarity the dummyData look like:

```
private dummyData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title 1',
        content: 'content 1',
        author: 'author 1'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        title: 'Title 2',
        content: 'content 2',
        author: 'author 1'
      }
    ];
```

Comment: I'm not sure the implementation you're looking for, but loadAll() could probably just be loadAll() { this._article$.next([Article, Article]); }

Comment: @JacobS so I was following along with https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services and he has an api, I was just trying to figure how I could avoid a http request but to continue development using an Observable where I could just sub in the ` this.http.get('${this.baseUrl}/articles')` later with a straight swap

Comment: You'll be subscribing to an observable either way. It won't care how the data is pushed into the observable. It should be a clean swap. If you want to retain the `this.http` call I would suggest the in-memory-api -https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-in-memory-web-api

Comment: @JacobS the problem is if I `this.http.get('${this.baseUrl}/articles').map(response => response.json())` to `Observable.from(this.dummyData)` I get the build error mentioned above i.e. `Type '{ id: number; title: string; content: string; author: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Article[]'`

Comment: Why do you name your var like this `_articles$`?

Comment: @angry-kiwi the Dollar sign is because it's an observable and the underscore is because it is private and has a getter `articles`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 1**

From https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#http

> @ANGULAR/HTTP/TESTING CLOSEST REPLACEMENT IN @ANGULAR/COMMON/HTTP/TESTING
>   MockBackend   ==> HttpTestingController
>   MockConnection ==> HttpTestingController

**Original**

You can use [`MockBackend`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html)

> ```
> import {BaseRequestOptions, Http} from '@angular/http';
> import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';
> it('should get some data', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
>   var connection;
>   var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
>     MockBackend,
>     {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
>       return new Http(backend, options);
>     }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}]);
>   var http = injector.get(Http);
>   var backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
>   //Assign any newly-created connection to local variable
>   backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
>   http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
>     expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
>     async.done();
>   });
>   connection.mockRespond(new Response('awesome'));
> }));
> ```

**Update**

Define the `dummyData` like:

```
private dummyData = {
  json: function() {
    return [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title 1',
        content: 'content 1',
        author: 'author 1'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        title: 'Title 2',
        content: 'content 2',
        author: 'author 1'
      }
    ]};
}
```

Comment: this would be perfect for testing and maybe my question is not clear enough (I will correct this) but what I would like to do is create an Observable from the Dummy data that can use the same subscribe as the http request

Comment: What `Observable` can **not** use the same subscribe? You mean that you can get the payload using `data.json()`. What's the purpose? You could also use `MockBackend` in normal code or `InMemoryBackendService` used in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: I was trying to use `Observable.from(this.dummyData)` instead of `this.http.get('${this.baseUrl}/articles').map(..)` but get the Type error mentioned in question

Comment: An object is not assignable to an array of objects. Add your data in an array and pass the array.

Comment: sorry if this is silly question but am I not doing that with `Observable.from(this.dummyData)` ? this.summyData is an array.

Comment: so with your addition and a change from `Observable.from(this.dummyData)` to  `Observable.create(()=> { return this.dummyData} )` I was able to get the result I wanted. Thank you

Comment: Hi  all, I have same kind of problem. But here I am trying to create environment sensitive mock. Here is my another question with same context. Please help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634007/angular2-setup-mock-environment-using-json-file

Comment: Things might have changed. Using Angular 2.4.0, rxjs 5.1.0, this worked for me: `Observable.create(observer => { observer.next(this.dummyData); });`