# angular2 setup mock environment using JSON file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to set up a mock environments as follows inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423716/environment-specific-service-endpoint-in-angular2-with-angular-cli).

**environment.mock.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  PRODUCT_LIST : 'http://localhost:4200/app/mock-json/products.json',
  SAVE_CART : 'http://localhost:4200/app/mock-json/cart.json'
};
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  PRODUCT_LIST : 'http://x.x.x.x:9000/service/products',
  SAVE_CART : 'http://x.x.x.x:9000/service/cart'
};
```

**Service Method**

```
getCartData (request: string):Promise<Cart[]>{
    return this.http.post(environment.SAVE_CART, request)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                        .....
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

While I am running with `ng serve` then everything is running fine with original service endpoint.

But while  I am using `ng serve --environment=mock` the Save Cart functionality is not working because of POST call. (All the GET call is working fine)

Actually I need to setup the structure in such a way that,

1. using `ng serve`. I could switch to original implementation which will use original service end points.
2. using `ng serve --environment=mock` I could switch to mock implementation which will uses JSON files.
3. At the time of switching I do not need to touch any code. For mock implementation a set of predefined data will be serve always since my JSON file is hard coded.

**Note:**
I have updated the main question to clarify the context what I am looking for.
Same kind of error I am getting in this following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/f6yJHsqRdfPk8xEC33t9?p=preview) (Please check console log). But note: this plunker does not implements the emvironments, so solving this plunker may not solve my problem.

Comment: your json is malformed in the plunker `{
  "name" : "Test",
  "value" : "Test"
}`

Comment: Then how the get request is working?

Comment: It wasnt.. GET worked after rectifying it

Comment: You cannot post to a .json file... Why not use the real mockService that is shipped with Angular (MockBackend  from '@angular/http/testing' ?

Comment: One thing come to my mind that at the time of mock env use if we can inherit and override Http post method to use get method? Will it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to figure it out with the following idea .

> At the time of mock environment use, if we can inherit and override Angular2 Http post
>   method to use get method

Here is the following code which solve my problem.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { ConnectionBackend, Http, Request, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class MockHttp  extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('Mock Http POST...');
        return super.get(url, options).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.status === 404) {
                console.log('404 error');
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I used the following provider in my AppModule

```
    { 
        provide: Http, 
        useFactory: (
            backend: XHRBackend,
            defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => {
                if(environment.MOCK){
                    return new MockHttp(backend, defaultOptions)
                }
                else {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                }
        },
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
```

And Introduced on new environment variable **MOCK** as this.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  MOCK : true,
  PRODUCT_LIST : .....
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your json was malformed. Check the updated plunker link.

[plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2pafJCgx4CjrE2frDlnP?p=preview)

mymodel.json:

```
{
  "name" : "Test",
  "value" : "Test"
}
```

Inorder to do post, you have to use [Mockbackend](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html) which is going to receive the post request.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058141/how-can-a-mock-a-http-observable-in-angular2-for-when-no-api-is-written)

Comment: Yes. You are right. Though my expectation is little different. I have updated again with more information.