# How to delay Observable which emits error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Assume I have function which makes http call and returns Observable with user details.

If user doesn't exist it returns Observable which emits error.

```js
// Get user by id
function getUser(id) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    if (id === 1) {
      obs.next('200 - User found');
      obs.complete();
    } else {
      obs.error('404 - User not found');
    }
  });
}

// This will print "200 - User found" in the console after 2 seconds
getUser(1)
  .delay(2000)
  .subscribe(r => console.log(r));

// !!! Delay will not work here because error emmited
getUser(2)
  .delay(2000)
  .subscribe(null, e => console.log(e));
```

Is there any way to **delay** Observable which emits **error**?

Comment: why do you delay it?

Comment: I want to delay every http request to the API regardless success it or not (to test how app will behave if response is too long)

Comment: are you writing tests? you should usually use browser network tab throttling capabilities to emulate long requests

Comment: I found 1 thread about mocking an api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058141/how-can-a-mock-a-http-observable-in-angular2-for-when-no-api-is-written  And another about how to simulate a timeout on an api call (it's not an error like you want but it can point you in the right direction): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719116/how-to-timeout-angular2-http-request

Comment: @Maximus, devtool network tab throttling is cool. But the problem not in http requests (it's just example). I'm curious why Observable doesn't delayed if it returns error.

Comment: @taras-d, see if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431627/2545680) makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious why Observable doesn't delayed if it returns error

Here is the source code of the `delay` operator:

```
class DelaySubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
  ...

  protected _next(value: T) {
    this.scheduleNotification(Notification.createNext(value)); <-------- notification is scheduled
  }

  protected _error(err: any) {
    this.errored = true;
    this.queue = [];
    this.destination.error(err); <-------- error is triggered immediately
  }

  protected _complete() {
    this.scheduleNotification(Notification.createComplete());
  }
}
```

Just as with every other operator, `delay` subscribes to the source stream - `getUser()` in your case - and notifies the listener. You can see from the source code that it doesn't schedule notification when an error occurs and trigger the `error` method on the observable immediately.

[Here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/delay) you can learn more about `delay` operator.

> I want to delay every http request to the API regardless success it or
> not (to test how app will behave if response is too long)

I recommend using `throttle` capabilities of the Chrome Debugging Tools (network tab).